# tikz doesn't work properly

Tags: tikz-pgf

I am trying to toy around with tikz and I have found that the result is strange. When I run the code given [here](http://www.texample.net/tikz/examples/state-machine/):

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pgf}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,automata}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[->,>=stealth',shorten >=1pt,auto,node distance=2.8cm,
                    semithick]
  \tikzstyle{every state}=[fill=red,draw=none,text=white]

  \node[initial,state] (A)                    {$q_a$};
  \node[state]         (B) [above right of=A] {$q_b$};
  \node[state]         (D) [below right of=A] {$q_d$};
  \node[state]         (C) [below right of=B] {$q_c$};
  \node[state]         (E) [below of=D]       {$q_e$};

  \path (A) edge              node {0,1,L} (B)
            edge              node {1,1,R} (C)
        (B) edge [loop above] node {1,1,L} (B)
            edge              node {0,1,L} (C)
        (C) edge              node {0,1,L} (D)
            edge [bend left]  node {1,0,R} (E)
        (D) edge [loop below] node {1,1,R} (D)
            edge              node {0,1,R} (A)
        (E) edge [bend left]  node {1,0,R} (A);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

I get this result:[image]
I'm using Ubuntu Natty machine.

Comment: What version of PGF are you using? To find out, you can put `\pgfversion` immediately after `\begin{document}` and compile the document again.

Comment: Works fine for me with PGF v2.10. @Jake: AFAIK Ubuntu Natty still uses TeXLive 2009 :-(

Comment: Version 2.00 and I have found my error. I was running latex and not pdflatex on the document

Comment: Wow, that's an interesting result of running LaTeX. You should add this as an answer and accept it, so the question won't be shown as unanswered anymore. Also, you should probably update your TeX distribution (or PGF, at least), PGF 2.00 lacks a number of useful very features (the ability to choose the alignment of text in nodes, for instance).

Comment: By compiling with `latex` + `dvips` + `ps2pdf` I get the same as when compiling with `pdflatex`, but `latex` + `dvipdfm(x)` doesn't work.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

(This answer builds on a number of the earlier comments, I decided to fill in the details since there is no answer currently.)  When you compile (reasonably complex) pgf code with latex by default the generated file has all sorts of postscript code in it that dvipdfm(x) can't handle -- lots of errors happen if you look at stderr while converting.  This is why dvips -> ps2pdf works, but dvipdfm does not work.

As I understand it pgf will choose what backend driver to use semi-automatically, and if you are running `latex` it will guess that you want to use dvips.  With pdflatex, it will of course automatically use the pdftex driver.  If you want to convert a dvi with pgf-generated code using dvipdfm(x), which has no intermediate .ps stage (unlike the similarly named dvipdf), you need to tell it to use the right driver.  So, if you want to do latex -> dvipdfm, you need to add the following line before loading pgf/tikz:

```
\def\pgfsysdriver{pgfsys-dvipdfm.def}
```

With this line, for me at least, the original code compiles and converts fine with this sequence of commands.  The driver system is documented in detail in \S 10.2 of the 2.1 manual.  So, in summary, it seems most likely to me that the error is not running `latex` instead of `pdflatex` per se, but running `latex` with a mismatch of the pgf driver and the conversion path.

Comment: To clarify, if you run `latex` with the `pgfsys-dvipdfm` backend driver, do you get the right result?

Comment: @Andrew yes, or at least I did.  (and I did confirm a very wrong result without doing that, though it is worth noting it didn't look at all like Yotam's wrong result.  But what exactly it looks like when it goes wrong is probably very dependent on versions of everything in the chain.)

Answer (score 1):

I got the same problem, I solved it:

- In Kile's settings -> configure Kile
- go to Tools -> Build
- search for `dvitopdf`
- change the command to `dvipdf` instead of `dvipdfmx` or something, like that.