# How do I Typeset the "center positive" sign

Tags: symbols

For the documentation of an electronic product I need to typeset the sign shown in the picture linked below. Who knows how to do this? Solutions that say "just add it as a picture" are not considered helpful…

[image]

A quick websearch for "center positive sign latex" did not lead to anything particulary useful.

Comment: Personally, I don't remember that among the common symbols there is the symbol you are looking for. Surely the best solution is to draw it or with `circuitikz` and make it a symbol with a macro.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Using [tikz](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/tikz) you can draw:

[image]

using the code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\tikzset{
  circ/.style={circle,draw, inner sep=0mm, minimum width=10pt}
}
\newcommand\widget{%
\begin{tikzpicture}[thick]
     \draw[fill=black](0,0) circle (2pt);
     \draw ([shift=(45:5pt)]0,0) arc [start angle=45, end angle=315, radius=5pt];
     \node[circ] at (-1,0) {-};
     \node[circ] at (1,0) {\tiny +};
     \draw($ (-1,0)+(5pt,0) $)--(-5pt,0);
     \draw(0,0)-- ($ (1,0)-(5pt,0) $);
  \end{tikzpicture}
}
\begin{document}

  \widget

\end{document}
```

**EDIT**

As pointed out in the comments, the code above does not play well when used with `dvipdfm` to compile from LaTeX to PDF (compiling with LaTeX is fine but `dvipdfm` produces errors). Looking at [tikz driver dvipdfm for positioning](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/225157/tikz-driver-dvipdfm-for-positioning) suggested the following modifications, which seem to fix this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\def\pgfsysdriver{pgfsys-dvipdfmx.def}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\tikzset{
  circ/.style={circle,draw, inner sep=0mm, minimum width=10pt}
}
\newcommand\widget{%
\begin{tikzpicture}[thick]
     \draw[fill=black](0,0) circle (2pt);
     \draw ([shift=(45:5pt)]0,0) arc [start angle=45, end angle=315, radius=5pt];
     \node[circ] at (-1,0) {-};
     \node[circ] at (1,0) {\tiny +};
     \draw($ (-1,0)+(5pt,0) $)--(-5pt,0);
     \draw(0,0)-- ($ (1,0)-(5pt,0) $);
  \end{tikzpicture}
}
\begin{document}

  \widget

\end{document}
```

That is, you need to add `\def\pgfsysdriver{pgfsys-dvipdfmx.def}`.

Comment: never used tikz before so i will Need some time to understand whats going on here but looks very promising. i m gonna test this out. end then encapsulate this into a custom command b/c im not gonna paste this everywhere where needed….

Comment: tried this out and it doesnt work Right out of the box... what are you compiling this with? Latex->dvi->pdf ? because everything else in my original document is compiled this way changing to latex->ps will be no real solution to the original problem

Comment: just saw you already made custom command so i m just renaming it to what i Need...

Comment: btw is the Tiny command really needed for the plus sign while not for the minus sign? this Looks kinda suspicious to me

Comment: @derbender These days most people compile straight to PDF using pdflatex. I just checked and compiling from latex to dvi to PDF also works. If you are getting compilation errors the most likely reason is that you need to update your TeX distribution. I am using TexLive 2018. I agree that using `\tiny` only on the `+` sign looks strange, but this produces a "symbol" that is closer to what appears in the OP. Probably the reason for this is that TeX does some fancy things with dashes so that `-`, `--` and `---` all do different things.

Comment: tried pdflatex for my main document and it fails to include all my jpg and png images (and there are a lot of them) so pdflatex is not my way to go. i am gonna update my miktex and then try again to compile the mwe and my main document to see if it makes any difference

Comment: uninstalled miktex reinstalled it straight from the offical Website, put it through all the package updates (about 90) and then recompiled the example: works with pdflatex doesnt with latex->dvi->pdf. the main document though still fails to include the jpg and png s of which i have so many when compiling with pdflatex… so the code above is helpful b/c working but not quite useable

Comment: @derbender What error message do you get? This is very strange because latex -> dvi -> pdf works fine for me with the code above. So, I suspect that the problem is elsewhere.

Comment: error is in the dvipdfm part of the compilation chain…. upped the log at pastebin see here       https://pastebin.com/sJYmUJg3

Comment: @derbender To convert to PDF I used `dvipdf`, which works. I confirm that `dvipdfm` fails. A quick search with google pulled up https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/18806/tikz-doesnt-work-properly, which seems to provide a fix. I'll edit...

Comment: works gotta test that Change in my main document any then only denote this as accepted answer.